# Continuous background color of adjacent cells

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, color, cells

I'm trying to make continuous blocks of cells so that their background colors are the same, but without breaks of white space between them.

E.g.

[image]

After some recent digging, I found the option "Show Expression", which converts the cell to its explicit contents that Mathematica can interpret. For example, the third cell in the image can be created by writing

```
CellPrint[
    Cell["Can we make all",
         "Text",
         Background->RGBColor[0.87,0.94,1]
        ]
 ]
```

Showing the expression gives more information than I need, which I've omitted in this example. (Things like `CellChangeTimes` and expression for symbols like the apostrophes. There was also an option specifying the grouping.)

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to use this code to my advantage so I can format the cells so that the line break between stays the same color.

I realize that with text, I can just start a new paragraph by hitting Return a few times, but I'm trying to include examples of Mathematica code for plots and the like.

**Edit:** Using Stephen's suggestion from the comments, I'm running into some minor issues with my graphics, as in the pic below. A quick fix is to add `Background->White` where appropriate. The top cell shows what happens when this option is left out, and the bottom shows when it's applied to `GraphicsRow`. Another has to be added elsewhere (in my case, to `Pane`) to remove the blue frame.

[image]

Comment: You can use the `CellMargins` option of `Cell` to do what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers my question... Could you perhaps give an example of the proper syntax? The documentation center doesn't quite address what I want to accomplish.

Comment: `Cell["Hello", "Text", CellMargins->{{66, 10}, {0, 0}}, Background->RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1]]` followed by `Cell["World", "Text", CellMargins->{{66, 10}, {0, 0}}, Background->RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1]]`.

Comment: I achieved this result by typing Hello and World in 2 successive text cells, then I selected the cell brackets, opened the option inspector, then I altered the values displayed at Cell Options / Display Options / CellMargins.

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks! I feel like there should be a more accessible way to accomplish this, perhaps through the Cell or Format toolbar. Fortunately, I only have to do this for a few cells (this time).

Comment: I have promoted my comment(s) to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possible way of doing this.

Type some text into 2 successive text cells, then select the cell brackets, open the option inspector (Format / Option Inspector ...) and alter the values displayed at Cell Options / Display Options / CellMargins.

For instance, if the 2 text items are "Hello" and "World", then the resulting Cell expressions might be (Cell / Show Expression)

```
Cell["Hello", "Text", CellMargins->{{66, 10}, {0, 0}},
  Background->RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1]]
```

and

```
Cell["World", "Text", CellMargins->{{66, 10}, {0, 0}}, 
  Background->RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1]]
```

where I have set the top and bottom margins both to be 0.