# Removing vertical/horizontal edges from some cell frames

Tags: formatting, cells

I recently asked [a question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84364/continuous-background-color-of-adjacent-cells) regarding adjusting adjacent cells' margins to make their background color appear continuous.

With these settings in place, I'd like to put a single frame around the entire block of cells as described in the pic below. I can't seem to find any options within the Options Inspector.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
CellPrint[CellGroup[{TextCell[StringJoin[Table["abcd ", {20}]], "Text",
    CellFrame -> {{1, 1}, {0, 1}}, CellMargins -> {{200, 200}, {0, 10}}], 
 TextCell[StringJoin[Table["abcd ", {20}]], "Text", 
    CellFrame -> {{1, 1}, {0, 0}}, CellMargins -> {{200, 200}, {0, 0}}], 
 TextCell[StringJoin[Table["abcd ", {20}]], "Text", 
    CellFrame -> {{1, 1}, {1, 0}}, CellMargins -> {{200, 200}, {10, 0}}]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Works great! I had assumed the default options had to be a fixed constant judging by the fact that the default setting for `CellFrame` is `0.8`. Thanks!

Comment: @user170231, glad it was useful. Thank you for the accept.