# Consistent cell background color when using CellFrameLabels

Tags: cells, background

Let's say I have the simple notebook

```
NotebookWrite[
 CreateDocument[], {Cell["Consider the line defined by", "Text", 
   CellMargins -> {{66, 10}, {0, 0}}, CellFrameLabelMargins -> 0, 
   Background -> GrayLevel[0.9]],
  Cell[BoxData[
    FormBox[RowBox[{"y", "=", "2", "x", "."}], TraditionalForm]], 
   "DisplayFormulaNumbered", CellMargins -> {{66, 10}, {0, 0}}, 
   CellFrameLabelMargins -> 0, Background -> GrayLevel[0.9]]}]
```

which looks like this:

[image]

How do I fill in the gray shading on the top and bottom of the `CellFrameLabel` (which is the equation number in this case)?

I've tried adjusting `CellMargins` and `CellFrameLabelMargins`, as can be seen in the given `Cell` expressions.

I've seen a few similar questions, including:

[Continuous background color of adjacent cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84364/continuous-background-color-of-adjacent-cells)

[Removing vertical/horizontal edges from some cell frames](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84580/removing-vertical-horizontal-edges-from-some-cell-frames?rq=1)

But I haven't seen a previous topic that addresses my particular question.

**EDIT: Possible Solution**

It never occurred to me until now to try **negative** values for `CellFrameLabelMargins`. By changing the `Options` for the `DisplayFormulaNumbered` cell to

`CellMargins -> {{66, 17}, {0, 0}}` and `CellFrameLabelMargins -> -23`,

I get:

[image]

which is what I want.

Comment: See my edit to my original question that sets forth a possible solution. So I guess I've kinda answered my own question. But I'll leave it in an unanswered state for now in case someone has a better approach.

Comment: That the way I do it too.  I hope there is a cleaner solution.